# Freeze app with mediarecorder on setVideoSize

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have tablet acer a500 with android 4.0.

I can record video by (target size: 176x144):

```
_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
camera.unlock();
_recorder.setCamera(camera);
_recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
_recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
_recorder.setOutputFile(outputPath);
_recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
_recorder.prepare();
```

But I want change size of recording video.

Have next supported sizes:

```
front
previewSize support size: width = 176 height = 144 aspect = 1,222222
previewSize support size: width = 320 height = 240 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 352 height = 288 aspect = 1,222222
previewSize support size: width = 640 height = 480 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 672 height = 378 aspect = 1,777778
previewSize support size: width = 720 height = 576 aspect = 1,250000
previewSize support size: width = 800 height = 600 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 1280 height = 720 aspect = 1,777778

videSizes support size: width = 176 height = 144 aspect = 1,222222
videoSizes support size: width = 320 height = 240 aspect = 1,333333
videoSizes support size: width = 352 height = 288 aspect = 1,222222
videoSizes support size: width = 640 height = 480 aspect = 1,333333
videoSizes support size: width = 720 height = 576 aspect = 1,250000
videoSizes support size: width = 1280 height = 720 aspect = 1,777778

back

previewSize support size: width = 176 height = 144 aspect = 1,222222
previewSize support size: width = 320 height = 240 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 352 height = 288 aspect = 1,222222
previewSize support size: width = 640 height = 480 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 672 height = 378 aspect = 1,777778
previewSize support size: width = 720 height = 576 aspect = 1,250000
previewSize support size: width = 800 height = 600 aspect = 1,333333
previewSize support size: width = 1280 height = 720 aspect = 1,777778
previewSize support size: width = 1920 height = 1080 aspect = 1,777778

videoSizes support size: width = 176 height = 144 aspect = 1,222222
videoSizes support size: width = 320 height = 240 aspect = 1,333333
videoSizes support size: width = 352 height = 288 aspect = 1,222222
videoSizes support size: width = 640 height = 480 aspect = 1,333333
videoSizes support size: width = 720 height = 576 aspect = 1,250000
videoSizes support size: width = 1280 height = 720 aspect = 1,777778
```

Set _recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480) after _recorder.setOutputFormat and have problem. Video start writes (I see file 3 kb) and application freezed. I try different size. But can worked only with two: 176x144 and 352x288.

On freeze I see long stack: http://bit.ly/Oa5O0D

Please, help me, how know solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution: problem will be, because I used video encoder VideoEncoder.Default. For acer default is h263. If change on MPEG_4_SP or H264, worked stable with any resolution. it remains to verify on devices with api less 3.x.